# sql server issue with inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currenlty have this code

```
SELECT JOB.JobID, A.adID, AR.ARNum
FROM dbo.vEvent AS E, dbo.[vAd] as A, dbo.[vAR] as AR, dbo.JOB_EVENT as JOB
INNER JOIN A ON A.eventID = E.eventID
INNER JOIN AR ON AR.eventID = A.eventID
INNER JOIN JOB ON JOB.EVENT_ID = E.eventID
WHERE year = '' AND season = '' AND month = ''
```

however; when I execute it in SQl server I get this error.

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'A'.
```

I don't understand, because all of my variables look correct to me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want

```
SELECT JOB.JobID, A.adID, AR.ARNum
FROM dbo.vEvent AS E
INNER JOIN dbo.[vAd] as A ON A.eventID = E.eventID
INNER JOIN dbo.[vAR] as AR ON AR.eventID = A.eventID
INNER JOIN dbo.JOB_EVENT as JOB ON JOB.EVENT_ID = E.eventID
WHERE year = '' AND season = '' AND month = ''
```

Comment: I get these errors with that statement.  Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "E.eventID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The multi-part identifier "E.eventID" could not be bound.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'JobID'.

Comment: Sorry removed the main table alias by accident. Edited - try now.

Comment: what was the issue with my original query?

Comment: @MasterP: The issue is simply that it's wrong. You can't write `FROM ... AS a, ... AS b INNER JOIN b ON ...`; you have to write either `FROM ... AS a INNER JOIN ... AS b ON ...` (modern syntax) or `FROM ... AS a, ... AS b WHERE ...` (ancient syntax).

Comment: +1 to @ruakh - you basically had a mix of ANSI-89 and ANSI-92 syntax. But the ANSI-89 syntax (comma separated list of tables, joins via WHERE) is deprecated - so think `table` join `table` on `condition` join `table` on `condition`...